# how can i open my array while array name is stored inside a variable?

Tags: android

I like to know that,I wanted to open an array whose name had been passed through an intent and the array is in string.XML how can I open the array?what I am trying to say is the array name and variable name is different but value inside the string variable is same as the array name.

Comment: Provide Full Description of Issue.

Comment: and code with input